# Expo Application Services - Is it possible to disable minification for preview & production builds?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps, expo-eas

I'm struggling with a [minification related issue in react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/1303) that doesn't seem to have a solution yet.

This is making EAS builds in preview to crash on startup so as temporary solution I wanted to disable minification for those builds.

Is this possible?

Thank you